# SQL Query on four tables with MySQL - 'intersection'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-match-all

I have 4 tables

```
POST:
id

POST_TAG:
post_id
tag_id
value

TAG:
id

SEARCH:
tag_id
post_tag_value
```

I need to query for **posts** who have **all** tags and values as rows in SEARCH table ( not just one equal value for a tag):

EDIT: Sorry for not providing current query and enough information.

```
SELECT POST.id FROM POST,POST_TAG, SEARCH
WHERE
      POST.id = POST_TAG.post_id AND
      POST_TAG.tag_id= SEARCH.tag_id AND
      POST_TAG.value = SEARCH.value;
```

It works if SEARCH table has one row. The problem is, when it has more. There should be less results, but there are actually more( if test with 2 rows, the proper results are the rows that are duplicated; I am lookng for **intersection** not union)

Added sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cfb9/1

The result from the query is '1','1','2' . It should be only '1', because it has both 'tags' while '2' has only one.

Comment: Great. Let's see what query you've got so far, and someone will help you out (edit it into your question, rather than adding it to the comments).

Comment: at least provide some data on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Read this question with a lot of ways to do this: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: Have you ever used SQL before? Did you already try?

Comment: Not clear requirement much. Show sample data and required output.

Comment: Post updated.I will soon add sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/393eb/39

```
SELECT pt.post_id
FROM SEARCH s INNER JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = s.tag_id AND pt.value = s.value
GROUP BY pt.post_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEARCH)
```

Please note that in your fiddle the post with id 0 should be returned as well since it has both `(0,'yes')` and `(1, 'yes')` tuples.

Comment: Point taken, 0 and 1 should be returned yes, so this is the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

According to your sqlfiddle, the answer might be this:

```
-- i want to select post that match to EVERY tag
-- the result of example data should be only '1'
SELECT POST.id as 'tag_id'
FROM POST,POST_TAG, SEARCH
WHERE
      POST.id = POST_TAG.post_id AND
      POST_TAG.tag_id= SEARCH.tag_id AND
      POST_TAG.value = SEARCH.value
GROUP BY POST.id
having COUNT(distinct POST_TAG.tag_id) = (select count(distinct tag_id) from POST_TAG);
```

Comment: This work, but creates a UNION of results instead an INTERSECTION

Comment: i want to select post that match to every tag
the result of example data should be only '1'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/393eb/1

Comment: @2fingers I've edit my answer, you may test it. Is this what you want?

Comment: You answer was useful. I just need to modify the last line so it counts tag_id from the SEARCH table.

I don't know if this is the optimal query but it sure works. Thanks!

Comment: if one day there is a post having more tags than the search is looking for it won't work, i guess you already knew that but i felt like reminding it.

Comment: @Sebas you are right, initially I've used `TAG` table but it wouldn't work the way OP wanted.